# How do you read X bytes from a file without using Get-Content

Tags: powershell

I want to read X bytes from a binary file via PowerShell, without using Get-Content.

I don't want to use Get-Content as the data is binary, may be large, has no line feeds, and I don't want to read any more of the file than I need to. And from googling it seems that Get-Content uses line feeds to limit how much data it reads, and I've no line feeds.

Answer (score 10):

> I don't want to use `Get-Content` as the data is binary, may be large, has no line feeds, and I don't want to read any more of the file than I need to

`Get-Content` allows you to read a limited stream of bytes from the start of the file with the `-Encoding` and `-TotalCount` parameters:

```
$numBytes = 10
$bytes = Get-Content .\file.bin -Encoding byte -TotalCount 10
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer I found for this was StreamReader, and in my example below I am reading the first 10 bytes of the file (but it could easily be changed to whatever you want).

NOTE: I am reading the data into a Char array (which is fine for my needs).

```
    $numBytes = 10 # You'll need to test the file length is valid before reading...
    [char[]]$bytes = new-object Char[] $numBytes
    $streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader(".\fileyMcFileFile.bin")
    $countBytesGot = $streamReader.Read($bytes, 0, $numBytes) 
    $streamReader.Dispose()
```

(I've answered my own question as it took me ages to work how to do this, couldn't find this solution anywhere, and thought it might help someone else).

Answer (score 3):

Update to [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64174426/2894535) for PowerShell 7.0. Instead of `-Encoding Byte`, you need to use `-AsByteStream`:

```
Get-Content -AsByteStream -TotalCount 0x40 output.bin | Format-Hex
```

Unfortunately, `-AsByteStream` isn't in turn available in Windows PowerShell 5.0, so if you need your script to be portable, you need to check version and do the following:

```
$AsByteStream = if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 7) { @{ 'AsByteStream' = $True } } else { @{ 'Encoding' = 'Byte' } }
Get-Content @AsByteStream -TotalCount 0x40 output.bin | Format-Hex
```